# Как проверить роль пользователя

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Роли по дефолту выдаются, но я не могу проверить роль, помогите пожалуйста
checkRole:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

export function checkRole (roles) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
  
  const token = (req.headers.authorization || '').replace(/Bearer\s?/, '');

  if (token) {
    try {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'secret123');

      req.userId = decoded._id;
      const {roles: userRoles} = jwt.verify(token, 'secret123')
            let hasRole = false
            userRoles.forEach(role => {
                if (roles.includes(role)) {
                    hasRole = true
                }
            })
            if (!hasRole) {
                return res.status(403).json({message: "У вас нет доступа"})
            }
            next();
    } catch (e) {
      return res.status(403).json({
        message: 'Нет доступа',
      });
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(403).json({
      message: 'Нет',
    });
  }
}};
```

routes:

```
import { checkRole } from '../utils/checkRole.js'
import { checkAuth } from '../utils/index.js'
const router = new Router()

// Create Post
// http://localhost:3002/api/posts
router.post('/', checkRole(["ADMIN"]), create)
```

Check auth работает:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

export default (req, res, next) => {
  const token = (req.headers.authorization || '').replace(/Bearer\s?/, '');

  if (token) {
    try {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'secret123');

      req.userId = decoded._id;
      next();
    } catch (e) {
      return res.status(403).json({
        message: 'Нет доступа',
      });
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(403).json({
      message: 'Нет доступа',
    });
  }
};
```

[image: при отправке запроса выдает такую ошибку, а при проверки авторизации все работает]

Comment: похоже, что в вашем случае checkRole должно быть фабрикой, т.е. функцией возвращающей функцию проверки

Comment: сбросьте токен сюда

Comment: сделайте console.log(userRoles) - что там будет?

Comment: @Jackson спасибо, не видит userRoles, осталось разобраться почему не видит)

Comment: @Jackson Oшибка была в синтаксисе , я пол недели перебирал код , а дело было в том что я вносил role в db , а пытался достать roles)

Comment: @PashaPofactu я так понимаю роли переехали с токена в базу данных? потому что в этом коде - роли ищутся в токене

Comment: @Jackson роль записывается в токен

Comment: @PashaPofactu а можно токен в студию? этот код должен норм работать тогда

Comment: @Jackson я написал чуть выше что разобрался, все работает, спасибо за помощь

Comment: ну было бы здорово все равно получить токен, в плане безопасности можете не волноваться - он и так видимый для всех будет